# Rviz2: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not run rviz2 due to lack of shared library, I tried to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libogre1.12.10
```

but it doesn't help

full error msg

```
user@pc:~$ rviz2
rviz2: error while loading shared libraries: libOgreMain.so.1.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

For any suggestions I would be eternally grateful : )

system: ubuntu 22.04, ros2codename: humble

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402022/rviz2:-error-while-loading-shared-libraries/) by [Orpiczy](https://answers.ros.org/users/103849/orpiczy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sourcing humble again fixed it to me.

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [samer.cana@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/98997/samer.cana@gmail.com/) with karma: 26 on 2023-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1